# Strange Numerical Behaviour of gcc Linker

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have a problem with as simple a C code as the following:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    printf ("%f\n", exp(1));
}
```

Replacing `1` with numbers smaller than `710` results in a successful compilation with the expected effect, but for numbers higher than that  , I get a linker error, of all things:

```
/tmp/ccqVnsno.o: In function `main': 
test.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `exp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tested this for numbers under 1000 with the following bash script:

```
for i in {0..1000}; do
    sed -i -r "s:[0-9]+:${i}:" test.c
    gcc -o test test.c
    ./test
done
```

Putting the `printf` statements in a for loop with `exp` of the index variable results in the same linkage error, regardless of upper bound.

What's going on here? Is the compiler recognizing 710 as some sort of limit for `long double`? Then why is the linker catching the error? Sorry for credulity, I'm new to C.

Comment: Sidenote: `exp` takes in `double`, not `long double`.

Comment: Which compiler and which version are you using?

Comment: Note that if you wrote a loop in the C code using a variable as the argument to `exp()`, you'd have to link with the maths library from the start (`-lm` where necessary; not necessary on macOS).

Comment: I tried but couldn't replicate this error on gcc 6.3.0. The given program prints `2.718282`. No error. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm using `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`

Comment: @J...S as per problem statement, the code as written works fine, but generates an error when `1` is replaced by a number `>= 710`

Comment: @psacawa Oh! Now I tried it `711`. It prints `inf` (probably because the value is too large). Still, no explicit error messages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My *guess* is that for smaller numbers the GCC compiler optimizes the [`exp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/exp) call into something else, but for larger numbers it needs the standard implementation which is in the math library. And the math library needs to be explicitly linked with.

You link with the math library by adding the option `-lm` when linking. It's the option `-l` (lower-case L) which tells the linker to link with a library, and `m` for the **m**ath library.

---

Regarding the possible optimizations of [the `exp` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/exp) you can call it with a small number, and then use a disassembler to check the generated code.

Comment: It seems you're right, [`exp` doesn't get called at all](https://godbolt.org/g/YRNHYe) unless the parameter is larger than ~`709`, the result is computed at compile time.

Comment: `exp(710)` is greater than the highest finite number double can represent in typical implementations, which means that it will have to report a range error, so the compiler just leaves it for the the library implementation to deal with.